# Verifying a Contract on BSCScan.com

Tags: solidity, binance-smart-chain

I created a cryptocurrency with the help of a friend of mine (it took us ages to copy-paste codes from here and there) and to edit the contract's info, which is crucial for me, I now need to verify the contract. Here's my contract address:

[0xe1c7a0d5e099a1f0c14b60b0c320423cf2f4543b](https://bscscan.com/address/0xe1c7a0d5e099a1f0c14b60b0c320423cf2f4543b#code)

and here is the code I used in Remix:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract HelpingArtistsAtRisk is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 initialsupply) public ERC20 ("Helping Artists At Risk", "HAAR"){
        _mint(msg.sender,initialsupply);}
}
```

It gives me error after error when I try to verify it. Here are the error messages:

> Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: " to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.
> --> myc

> ParserError: Source "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
> --> myc:3:1:
> |
> 3 | import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol"

> BEP-20.sol:1:1: Error: Compiler version >=0.8.0 does not satisfy the r semver requirement

> ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library/struct/enum/constant/function definition.
> --> myc:1:1:
> |
> 1 | "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED"
> | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

I just wanted to have the BSCSCAN's verification.

Answer (score 0):

Since solidity 0.6.8 you should set a License header to your contract, so you need to add this at the first line of your file:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
```

You can use the UNLICENSED or use one of the predefined licenses. Here is the list: https://spdx.org/licenses/

More information about the SPDX License herader here: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/solidity-0-6-8-introduces-spdx-license-identifiers/2859

This should fix your first Warning and the last error.

After making this change I was able to compile the contract using remix, but I think that all other errors are related with the compiler version, could you share version and other settings that you see in the compiler options?

I'm using Compiler 0.8.4+commit.c7e474f2

Also you need to remove the public keyword in the constructor, it is ignored by the compiler. The final result is:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract HelpingArtistsAtRisk is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 initialsupply) ERC20 ("Helping Artists At Risk", "HAAR"){
        _mint(msg.sender,initialsupply);}
}
```

Comment: First of all let me thank you for taking the time and responding to my question. Very kind of you. The compiler version is 0.8.1+df193b15- Language: Solidity - EVM Version: Compiler Default - Auto Compile is checked.

Comment: I tried compiling with 0.8.4 as you wrote and it gave me the following error: ParserError: Source "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
 --> myc:5:1:
  |
5 | import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol"

Comment: I receive this error in BSCSCAN when I try to compile for verification: ParserError: Source "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
 --> myc:5:1:
  |
5 | import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol"

Comment: I'm very sorry to bother you, man. But can you verify it at BSCSCAN from there? My internet is too slow and filtered. This gentleman has a solution which I have absolutely no idea what it is and how to do that. Our aim in to help artists at risk. That's why we are doing that. But it seems impossible from Iran, considering restrictions and all that. Here's the. link: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/verify-smart-contract-inheriting-from-openzeppelin-contracts/4119

Comment: Are you triying to compile it in remix or are you using solc?. According to this https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/layout-of-source-files.html#use-in-actual-compilers -- Remix can compile the import "github.com/.." links but you need to download the source and map it with the imports in your contracts if you're using solc.